# Hiding .php extensions?

Tags: apache-http-server, ubuntu-11.10, php5

I'm having trouble hiding .php extensions on my site.

for example: I want
http://mysite.net/view_category.php?id=4
to show as
http://mysite.net/view_category?id=4

I'm sure it's to do with the .htaccess file, but I have no idea how to do it :<
I'm using apache2 and php5, ubuntu 11.10

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: in the question would or should (show as).

Comment: edited to make sense :)

Answer (score 2):

This question's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8371634/hide-php-extension-htaccess) has already been posted on Stack Overflow... but it fits here as well.

@ryanve suggests using this in .htaccess. That question is also linked to another solution.

```
RewriteEngine On 

# Unless directory, remove trailing slash 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Redirect external .php requests to extensionless url 
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(.+)\.php([#?][^\ ]*)?\ HTTP/ 
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://example.com/folder/$1 [R=301,L] 

# Resolve .php file for extensionless php urls 
RewriteRule ^([^/.]+)$ $1.php [L]
```